# Help with understanding K&R exercises

Tags: c

I am reading the book by kerninghan Ritchie Edition 2. It contains a code function on `getch()`, `ungetch()`, `getop()`, etc. I am not able to understand the stuff and I feel that it is bit incomplete also. Therefore, I am posting the question here.

Not able to understand... what getch(), ungetch() functions are doing. Please give few examples to demonstrate these functions.

At the end. these getch() and ungetch(0 functions are used by getOp(). What does this function doing. Only examples willl do. No code explanations reqd.That i will try and manage myself. If i have some sample examples.

Please give few examples to make this code look pretty easier; if there is any correction in the programm, then please let me know.

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define BUFSIZE 100

char buf[BUFSIZE];      /* buffer for ungetch */
int bufp = 0;           /* next free position in buf */

int getch(void) /* get a (possibly pushed-back) character */
{
   return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

void ungetch(int c)     /* push character back on input */
{
   if(bufp >= BUFSIZE)
      printf(" ungetch too many characters\n");

   else
      buf[bufp++] = c;
}

/* getop: get next character or numeric operand */
int getop(char s[])
{
   int i, c;

   while ((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t');

   s[1] = '\0';

   if(!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
      return c;         /* not a number */

   i=0;
   if(isdigit(c))       /* collect integer part */
      while(isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()));

   if(c == '.')         /* collect fractional part */
      while(isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()));

   s[i] = '\0';
   if (c != EOF)
      ungetch(c);

}
```

Comment: Try asking a specific question. Which part are you having difficulty with ?

Comment: The ellipsis is made of only three dots. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis

Comment: Did you read from the start? What part don't you understand? Your question is too unspecific. Someone could start explaining the braces and whitespace and it would seem just as valid, you know.

Comment: I've edited your title to reflect the body of your question a bit better. Those seeing it will immediately know that you are working through the exercises in K&R and need some additional guidance.

Comment: I've also moved the body of your post above the code, so that people can read your entire question in one place. Please feel free to revert either of my edits if this is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo here:

```
  while(isdigit([s++i] = c = getch()));
```

Change it to:

```
  while(isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()));
```

Comment: Not really an answer - should have been a comment.

Comment: The submitter asked for any corrections in the program, so Paul gave the submitter one.  I don't see whats wrong.

Comment: @ChrisF - The OP did ask for code review. This answer is much better than the typical comment form of `please post code that compiles!` ...

Comment: @Tim - I assumed that he was after an explanation of what the code did, and that he'd copied the code out of K&R, so any mistakes would just be typos. Though I did miss the sentence before the code!

Comment: @ChrisF - I just edited the question some, it was kind of difficult to figure out exactly what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, I thought it was incomplete as well, but then I noticed the following key line:

```
return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
```

On the off chance you weren't aware, the a ? b : c syntax is a ternary statement meaning "if a is true, execute b, else execute c". In this case, what happens is that, if `bufp`, the count of characters in the array `buf`, is greater than 0, `getch()` will decrement `bufp` and return the last character in the buffer (meaning the buffer actually acts as a stack, since `ungetch()` adds characters to the tail of the buffer rather than the head). If there are no characters in `buf` (i.e. `bufp` <= 0), the function calls `getchar()` and returns the value obtained from that. Aside from that, I don't see where your confusion could be coming from, unless your problem really does stem from that typo that Paul R mentioned and everything before this sentence is pointless.

Comment: Well.. This much portion is clearer to me.... It would be better if you could give 1-2 examples, to support this explanation.. thanks..

Answer (score 1):

getchar() reads and eliminates from stdin. What you read is lost iff you are not keeping it.
this is where the pop and push functions getch() and ungetch() com into play. in getop you have a small parser with a look-ahead of 1 (one character in advance).

getop()

- skip blanks and tabs
- if c is no digit and no dot, return this character
- read over numbers and dot and more numbers
- if read character is not a number, push it back and leave function